# How to find out if a particular song/artist/album belongs to the users favourites while using deezer search API?

Tags: deezer

Is there any way to get this information implicitly? Or how can I ask whether object xxx belongs to the users favourite library or not?

It would be great to be able to display whether a particular object belongs to the users favourite library. For example a boolean "isFavorite" property in the objects returned by deezers search API?

The official deezer web player for example shows a fullfilled heart, when a favourite song is within my search result or in a album I opened.

Thanks in advance!
Best,
Frime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right, it is implemented on our website player, but will not be in our REST API unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks! You don't plan to add this feature in the future? It would be very helpful...